# Repeating alarms for Google Calendar

Tags: software-rec, google-calendar, alarm

I've always wanted to [set up repeating alarms for Google Calendar](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-discuss/xr66NmL98SQ) (that turn off when the "off" button is pressed.) If it isn't possible to choose this option from Google Calendar itself, Is there any third-party software that can do this? I'm using Ubuntu, and also dual-booting Windows.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: It appears that the CalAlarm app supports such a feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Google Chrome extension [Alarm](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fdjkdjnaajdmnminlhhhcicfnokdhjfg?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon), I'm not so sure, but I think it has what your looking for.

I'll edit my answer if I find something else/better or if you provide a little more detail for the features your looking for.

Edit:  I think [Remember The Milk](http://goo.gl/3s8HT) is what your looking for."In addition to the powerful web app... mobile to the web to apps including Gmail, Google Calendar, Twitter, and more. Remember The Milk apps are available for Android, iPhone, and iPad, and the MilkSync service syncs with Microsoft Outlook..."

It mentions Google Calendar specifically, and the "details" tab mentioned feature to sort alarms by ..."repeating".

Comment: Does "Alarm" have the ability to set Google Calendar alarms that repeat until dismissed by the user? Also, does it synchronize the alarms across multiple Chrome installations?

Comment: Also, I'd like to know whether similar software is available for mobile operating systems such as the iPod Touch.

Comment: @AndersonGreen Oh, so you want a calendar that will sink with your moil device, and Google Calendar.  OK.

Comment: I also want the alarm to repeat in a loop until it is dismissed by the user.

Comment: @AndersonGreen  I think [Remember The Milk](http://goo.gl/3s8HT) is what your looking for... If not, just post a comment to that effect.

Comment: Which feature of Remember the Milk are you referring to, specifically? I haven't yet figured out how to set alarms for RTM.

Comment: RTM?  What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean "Remember The Milk." I was using an acronym.